# Map Reduce with F# agents

Tags: f#, mapreduce, agents

After playing with F# agents I tried to do a map reduce using them.

The basic structure I use is:

- map supervisor which queues up all the work to do in its state and receives work request from map workers
- reduce supervisor does the same thing as map supervisor for reduce work
- a bunch of map and reduce workers that map and reduce, if one fails its work it sends it back to the respective supervisr to be reprocessed.

The questions I wonder about is:

- does this make any sense compared to a more traditional (yet very nice) map reduce like (http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-parallel-aggregate.aspx) that uses PSeq ?
- the way I implemented the map and reduce workers seems ugly is there a better way ?
- it seems like I can create a 1000 000 map workers and 1000 0000 reduce workers lol, how should I choose these numbers, the more the better ?

Thanks a lot,

```
type Agent<'T> = MailboxProcessor<'T>

//This is the response the supervisor
//gives to the worker request for work
type 'work SupervisorResponse =
| Work of 'work //a piece of work
| NoWork//no work left to do 

//This is the message to the supervisor
type 'work WorkMsg = 
| ToDo of 'work //piles up work in the Supervisor queue
| WorkReq of   AsyncReplyChannel<SupervisorResponse<'work>> //' 

//The supervisor agent can be interacted with
type AgentOperation = 
| Stop //stop the agent
| Status //yield the current status of supervisor

type 'work SupervisorMsg = 
| WorkRel of 'work WorkMsg
| Operation of AgentOperation 

//Supervises Map and Reduce workers
module AgentSupervisor= 
    let getNew (name:string) = 
        new Agent<SupervisorMsg<'work>>(fun inbox -> //'
            let rec loop state  = async {
                let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                match msg with 
                | WorkRel(m) -> 
                    match m with 
                    | ToDo(work) -> 
                        let newState = work:state
                        return! loop newState
                    | WorkReq(replyChannel) ->  
                        match state with 
                        | [] -> 
                            replyChannel.Reply(NoWork)
                            return! loop []
                        | [item] -> 
                            replyChannel.Reply(Work(item))
                            return! loop []
                        | (item::remaining) -> 
                            replyChannel.Reply(Work(item))
                            return! loop remaining
                | Operation(op) -> 
                    match op with 
                    | Status -> 
                        Console.WriteLine(name+" current Work Queue "+
                                            string (state.Length))
                        return! loop state
                    | Stop -> 
                        Console.WriteLine("Stoppped SuperVisor Agent "+name)
                        return()
            }
            loop [] )
    let stop (agent:Agent<SupervisorMsg<'work>>) = agent.Post(Operation(Stop))
    let status (agent:Agent<SupervisorMsg<'work>>) =agent.Post(Operation(Status))

//Code for the workers
type 'success WorkOutcome = 
| Success of 'success
| Fail

type WorkerMsg = 
| Start
| Stop
| Continue

module AgentWorker = 
    type WorkerSupervisors<'reduce,'work> = 
        { Map:Agent<SupervisorMsg<'work>> ; Reduce:Agent<SupervisorMsg<'reduce>> }

    let stop (agent:Agent<WorkerMsg>) = agent.Post(Stop)
    let start (agent:Agent<WorkerMsg>) = agent.Start()
                                         agent.Post(Start)

    let getNewMapWorker( map, supervisors:WorkerSupervisors<'reduce,'work>  ) = 
        new Agent<WorkerMsg>(fun inbox ->  
            let rec loop ()  = async {
                let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                match msg with 
                | Start -> inbox.Post(Continue)
                           return! loop ()
                | Continue ->   
                    let! supervisorOrder = 
                    supervisors.Map.PostAndAsyncReply(
                        fun replyChannel -> 
                            WorkRel(WorkReq(replyChannel)))
                    match supervisorOrder with 
                    | Work(work) -> 
                        let! res = map work 
                        match res with
                        | Success(toReduce) -> 
                            supervisors.Reduce
                                .Post(WorkRel(ToDo(toReduce)))
                        | Fail -> 
                            Console.WriteLine("Map Fail")
                            supervisors.Map
                                .Post(WorkRel(ToDo(work)))
                            inbox.Post(Continue)
                   | NoWork -> 
                            inbox.Post(Continue)
                            return! loop ()
                | Stop -> 
                    Console.WriteLine("Map worker stopped")
                    return ()
                }
            loop ()  )


    let getNewReduceWorker(reduce,reduceSupervisor:Agent<SupervisorMsg<'work>>)=//'
        new Agent<WorkerMsg>(fun inbox ->  
            let rec loop ()  = async {
                let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                match msg with
                | Start -> inbox.Post(Continue)
                           return! loop()
                | Continue ->   
                    let! supervisorOrder = 
                        reduceSupervisor.PostAndAsyncReply(fun replyChannel -> 
                            WorkRel(WorkReq(replyChannel)))
                    match supervisorOrder with 
                    | Work(work) -> 
                        let! res = reduce work 
                        match res with 
                        | Success(toReduce) -> inbox.Post(Continue)
                        | Fail -> 
                            Console.WriteLine("ReduceFail")
                            reduceSupervisor.Post(WorkRel(ToDo(work)))
                            inbox.Post(Continue)
                    | NoWork -> inbox.Post(Continue)
                    return! loop()
                |Stop ->Console.WriteLine("Reduce worker stopped"); return () 
                }
            loop() )

open AgentWorker

type MapReduce<'work,'reduce>( numberMap:int , 
                               numberReduce: int, 
                               toProcess:'work list,  
                               map:'work->Async<'reduce WorkOutcome>,
                               reduce:'reduce-> Async<unit WorkOutcome>) = 

    let mapSupervisor= AgentSupervisor.getNew("MapSupervisor")  
    let reduceSupervisor  = AgentSupervisor.getNew("ReduceSupervisor")

    let workerSupervisors = {Map = mapSupervisor ; Reduce = reduceSupervisor }

    let mapWorkers = 
        [for i in 1..numberMap -> 
            AgentWorker.getNewMapWorker(map,workerSupervisors) ]
    let reduceWorkers = 
        [for i in 1..numberReduce -> 
            AgentWorker.getNewReduceWorker(reduce,workerSupervisors.Reduce) ] 

    member this.Start() = 
        //Post work to do
        toProcess
        |>List.iter(fun elem -> mapSupervisor.Post( WorkRel(ToDo(elem))))
        //Start supervisors
        mapSupervisor.Start()
        reduceSupervisor.Start()
        //start workers 
        List.iter( fun mapper -> mapper |>start) mapWorkers 
        List.iter( fun reducer ->reducer|>start) reduceWorkers

    member this.Status() =  (mapSupervisor|>AgentSupervisor.status)
                            (reduceSupervisor|>AgentSupervisor.status)
    member this.Stop() = 
        List.map2(fun mapper reducer -> 
            mapper |>stop; reducer|>stop) mapWorkers reduceWorkers

//Run some tests
let map = function (n:int64) -> async{ return Success(n) } 

let reduce = function (toto: int64) -> async{ return Success() }

let mp = MapReduce<int64,int64>( 1,1,[for i in 1L..1000000L->i],map,reduce)

mp.Start()
mp.Status()
mp.Stop()
```

Comment: FYI, I'm not reading a question that contains more than 120 lines of (poorly-formatted) code.

Comment: @Brian, Sorry for the messiness, have tried  to reformat things  a bit, but still have the color problem which makes all of it terribly ugly. Note I am not really hoping that anyone reads all the  120 lines of my code, I just put it their in case it can clear my question. Thanks

Comment: I made some edits to clean it up more. In particular, it uses less horizontal and vertical whitespace (no need to scroll right, no multiple-blank-lines-in-a-row). Also, note use of //' as a way to avoid SO mis-coloring multiple lines

Comment: IMHO it's counterproductive to try and rename F# built-in methods, types, etc.  It may make sense on your own desk as you're trying to learn, but it hurts readability in public forums.

Comment: IMHO another thing that makes this code hard to read is the unions inside unions business.  It's similar to switch inside switch in C# when it comes to reading the match constructs.

Comment: I may not understand your code fully, but if i were to write a reduce step, I would really try to keep it within the same synchronization context, or on the same MailboxProcessor of T.

Comment: @GregC - if you're talking about renaming `MailboxProcessor` to `Agent`, I think that this is actually a pretty well established type abbreviation (e.g. see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/02/15/async-and-parallel-design-patterns-in-f-part-3-agents.aspx).

Comment: @kvb In Scala they are called Actors, as in "Actor-based synchronization model."  In Erlang, processes... A rose by any other name...  If Don Syme says Agent<T>, then why in the world is it MailboxProcessor<T> in the RTM drop?

Comment: @kvb, @GregC I used Don Syme blog post, hence the Agent<T>

Answer (score 6):

I like to use MailboxProcessor for the reduce part of the algorithm, and async block that's invoked with Async.Parallel for the map part.  It makes things more explicit, giving you finer control over exception handling, timeouts, and cancellation.

The following code was designed with Brian's help, and with the help of his excellent F# block highlighting "F# Depth Colorizer" plug-in for VS2010.

This code is meant to pull RSS feeds from yahoo weather server in a map-reduce pattern.  It demonstrates how we can control execution flow from the outside of actual algorithm.

fetchWeather is the map part, and mailboxLoop is the reduce part of the algorithm.

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"

#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll"

open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.IO
open System.Linq
open System.Net
open System.Xml.Linq

open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions 

type Weather (city, region, temperature) = class
   member x.City = city
   member x.Region = region
   member x.Temperature : int = temperature

   override this.ToString() =
      sprintf "%s, %s: %d F" this.City this.Region this.Temperature
end

type MessageForActor = 
   | ProcessWeather of Weather
   | ProcessError of int
   | GetResults of (Weather * Weather * Weather list) AsyncReplyChannel

let parseRss woeid (rssStream : Stream) =
   let xn str = XName.Get str
   let yweather elementName = XName.Get(elementName, "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0")

   let channel = (XDocument.Load rssStream).Descendants(xn "channel").First()
   let location   = channel.Element(yweather "location")
   let condition  = channel.Element(xn "item").Element(yweather "condition")

   //  If the RSS server returns error, condition XML element won't be available.
   if not(condition = null) then
      let temperature = Int32.Parse(condition.Attribute(xn "temp").Value)
      ProcessWeather(new Weather(
                    location.Attribute(xn "city").Value,
                    location.Attribute(xn "region").Value,
                    temperature))
   else
      ProcessError(woeid)

let fetchWeather (actor : MessageForActor MailboxProcessor) woeid =
   async {
      let rssAddress = sprintf "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=%d&u=f" woeid
      let webRequest =  WebRequest.Create rssAddress
      use! response = webRequest.AsyncGetResponse()
      use responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
      let weather = parseRss woeid responseStream
      //do! Async.Sleep 1000 // enable this line to see amplified timing that proves concurrent flow
      actor.Post(weather)
   }

let mailboxLoop initialCount =
   let chooseCityByTemperature op (x : Weather) (y : Weather) =
      if op x.Temperature y.Temperature then x else y

   let sortWeatherByCityAndState (weatherList : Weather list) =
      weatherList
      |> List.sortWith (fun x y -> x.City.CompareTo(y.City))
      |> List.sortWith (fun x y -> x.Region.CompareTo(y.Region))

   MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
      let rec loop minAcc maxAcc weatherList remaining =
         async {
            let! message = inbox.Receive()
            let remaining = remaining - 1

            match message with
            | ProcessWeather weather ->
               let colderCity = chooseCityByTemperature (<) minAcc weather
               let warmerCity = chooseCityByTemperature (>) maxAcc weather
               return! loop colderCity warmerCity (weather :: weatherList) remaining
            | ProcessError woeid ->
               let errorWeather = new Weather(sprintf "Error with woeid=%d" woeid, "ZZ", 99999)
               return! loop minAcc maxAcc (errorWeather :: weatherList) remaining
            | GetResults replyChannel ->
               replyChannel.Reply(minAcc, maxAcc, sortWeatherByCityAndState weatherList)
         }

      let minValueInitial = new Weather("", "", Int32.MaxValue)
      let maxValueInitial = new Weather("", "", Int32.MinValue)
      loop minValueInitial maxValueInitial [] initialCount
      )

let RunSynchronouslyWithExceptionAndTimeoutHandlers computation =
   let timeout = 30000
   try
      Async.RunSynchronously(Async.Catch(computation), timeout)
      |> function Choice1Of2 answer               -> answer |> ignore
                | Choice2Of2 (except : Exception) -> printfn "%s" except.Message; printfn "%s" except.StackTrace; exit -4
   with
   | :? System.TimeoutException -> printfn "Timed out waiting for results for %d seconds!" <| timeout / 1000; exit -5

let main =
   // Should have script name, sync/async select, and at least one woeid
   if fsi.CommandLineArgs.Length < 3 then
      printfn "Expecting at least two arguments!"
      printfn "There were %d arguments" (fsi.CommandLineArgs.Length - 1)
      exit -1

   let woeids =
      try
         fsi.CommandLineArgs
         |> Seq.skip 2 // skip the script name and sync/async select
         |> Seq.map Int32.Parse
         |> Seq.toList
      with
      | except -> printfn "One of supplied arguments was not an integer: %s" except.Message; exit -2

   let actor = mailboxLoop woeids.Length

   let processWeatherItemsConcurrently woeids =
      woeids
      |> Seq.map (fetchWeather actor)
      |> Async.Parallel
      |> RunSynchronouslyWithExceptionAndTimeoutHandlers

   let processOneWeatherItem woeid =
      woeid
      |> fetchWeather actor
      |> RunSynchronouslyWithExceptionAndTimeoutHandlers

   let stopWatch = new Stopwatch()
   stopWatch.Start()
   match fsi.CommandLineArgs.[1].ToUpper() with
   | "C" -> printfn "Concurrent execution:  "; processWeatherItemsConcurrently woeids
   | "S" -> printfn "Synchronous execution: "; woeids |> Seq.iter processOneWeatherItem
   | _   -> printfn "Unexpected run options!"; exit -3

   let (min, max, weatherList) = actor.PostAndReply GetResults
   stopWatch.Stop()
   assert (weatherList.Length = woeids.Length)

   printfn "{"
   weatherList |> List.iter (printfn "   %O")
   printfn "}"
   printfn "Coldest place: %O" min
   printfn "Hottest place: %O" max
   printfn "Completed in %d millisec" stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds

main
```