# usable free weather service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Is there any long time usable free service on the web that I can use to read and write information into my application, I need a free weather service to display my city temperature as a markee text running on my window title.

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be two questions.  One is about fetching weather info from web.  Another is about a marquee text on a window title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for weather web service...  [Here's the first hit.](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/)

[Here's some of my F# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4438256/90475) that can be easily translated to C#, using Yahoo web service.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out Yahoo Weather: http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Comment: Thank you, I'll be back to this problem tomorrow night

Answer (score 0):

The Norwegian Meteorological Institute have free for commercial use weather [The Norwegian Meteorological Institute](http://api.met.no/).
Or you may use Open Weather Map [Open weather map](http://openweathermap.org/).

You can use this library: [CSharp_Weather](https://github.com/Miro382/CSharp_Weather)
It is very easy to use library for .NET.