# Properway to dispose of class in Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#

I have a simple Parallel.Foreach loop that has about 1000 rows in the DataTable, each of these Rows calls a new Class, however, the memory builds up until i run out of memory.  I'm wondering how to you dispose to a new Class properly in regards to a parallel.  If you're saying what a newb question it's because Parallel and Threading is new to me.

```
  var options = new ParallelOptions();
        options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5;
        Parallel.ForEach(urlTable.AsEnumerable(),options, drow =>
        {
            WebSiteCrawlerClass WCC = new WebSiteCrawlerClass();
            if (drow.ItemArray[0].ToString().Contains("$"))
            {

                WCC.linkGrabberwDates(drow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
            }
            else
            {
                WCC.NoDatesCarCrawler(drow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If WebSiteCrawlerClass is disposable then you would do this

```
    using( var WCC = new WebSiteCrawlerClass() )
    {
        if (drow.ItemArray[0].ToString().Contains("$"))
        {
            WCC.linkGrabberwDates(drow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
        }
        else
        {
            WCC.NoDatesCarCrawler(drow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
        }
    }
```

Comment: okay, let me make the new dumb question, how do I know or how do i make a class disposable

Comment: It doesn't need to be disposable unless it holds references to instances of other disposable types, or non-managed resources.  The methods of the class need to dispose any disposable object they create as well.  Search for IDisposable/Disposable pattern.

Comment: so basically WebSiteCrawlerClass() : IDisposable

Comment: Yes but just adding a Dispose method won't help unless you use is correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem can be better addressed with async instead of Parallel.  Dish out all the requests, and process them as they come back to ya.  Just a thought.

Comment: I've done similar things in F#, but it translates to C#/Async pretty well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431743/map-reduce-with-f-agents/4438256#4438256

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is have a single WebSiteCrawlerClass object for each thread instead of initializing one for each loop.  This can be done using the 'localInit' overload of [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783538.aspx).  Something like:

```
    var options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5;
    Parallel.ForEach(urlTable.AsEnumerable(),
      options,
      () => new WebSiteCrawlerClass(),
      (drow, dummyLoopState, WCC) =>
      {
        if (drow.ItemArray[0].ToString().Contains("$"))
        {
            WCC.linkGrabberwDates(drow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
        }
        else
        {
            WCC.NoDatesCarCrawler(drow.ItemArray[0].ToString(), "www");
        }
        return WCC;
      },
      (wcc) => { } );
```

This assumes your WebSiteCrawlerClass object is reusable.  If you need to reset its state or something, that is done during the Finally delegate at the end (so something like `(wcc) => { wcc.Reset(); }` at the end).